# cant see what i did wrong (simple animation)

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  background: hsl(210, 100%, 95%);
}
#Title {
  font-family: Lobster, monospace;
  font-size: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
 h1:hover {
   color: black;
   transform: scale(1.2)
}
.circles {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:solid;
  position:fixed;
  animation-name: 123;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}

#circle1 {

  animation-timing-function: linear;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ccffff, #ffcccc);
  left:50%;
}
#circle2 {

  animation-timing-function: linear;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #A52A2A 2px, #cccccc 5px, orange 10px);
  left:25%;
}


@keyframes 123 {
  50% {
  bottom: 10%;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <head>
    <title>Animation-1</title>
    </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="Title">Placeholder</h1>

      <div class="circles" id="circle1">        </div>
      <div class="circles" id="circle2">        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Gone over it 3 times already, can't see where im messing up

Comment: **1st** is keyframe with number is not accepted. **2nd** In you keyframe you need to specify `0%` and `100%` as well.

Answer (score 1):

try to use string instead of number in keyframes naming

here is your animation example. https://codepen.io/baomastr/pen/KKgNGbg

```css
.circles {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: test;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

#circle1 {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ccffff, #ffcccc);
  left: 50%;
}

#circle2 {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    #a52a2a 2px,
    #cccccc 5px,
    orange 10px
  );
  left: 25%;
}

@keyframes test {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circles" id="circle1"> </div>
<div class="circles" id="circle2"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1st** is keyframe with number is not accepted. **2nd** In you keyframe you need to specify `0%` and `100%` as well. To be for example like:

```css
@keyframes slidein {
   0%   { bottom: 60%; }
   50%  { bottom: 10%; }
   100% { bottom: 0%; }
}
```

### DEMO:

```css
body {
  background: hsl(210, 100%, 95%);
}
#Title {
  font-family: Lobster, monospace;
  font-size: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
 h1:hover {
   color: black;
   transform: scale(1.2)
}
.circles {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:solid;
  position:fixed;
  animation-name: slidein;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}

#circle1 {

  animation-timing-function: linear;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ccffff, #ffcccc);
  left:50%;
}
#circle2 {

  animation-timing-function: linear;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #A52A2A 2px, #cccccc 5px, orange 10px);
  left:25%;
}


@keyframes slidein {
  0%   { bottom: 60%; }
  50%  { bottom: 10%; }
  100% { bottom: 0%; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <head>
    <title>Animation-1</title>
    </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="Title">Placeholder</h1>

      <div class="circles" id="circle1">        </div>
      <div class="circles" id="circle2">        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```